# Should i ise unicode for Special characters in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, special-characters

I have a Reactjs application with react-intl translation module.
For translation, i store all messages in javascript files like this :

```
export default {
'key_label_1': 'Tableau des départs & arrivées',
}
```

Can i use accent in javascript string or should i use unicode ?
Is there any good reference or explanation of the best practices for that ?

Comment: "Can i use accent in javascript string" — Have you tried it? Do you have some reason to believe you can't?

Comment: "or should i use unicode" — Why "or"? Unicode is how you include accented characters in text files (which are what JavaScript programs are stored in). At least this century. ISO-8859 was still commonly used two decades ago.

Comment: "Is there any good reference or explanation of the best practices for that ?" — Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: don't be so severe, i only ask for best practice on special character in string ... I'm not talking about book, tools or framework